How to create mutil dialog with nsDialogs::Create 1018, when my install need mutil dialog
Page custom Page1Create Page1Leave PAGE_CUSTOM_FIRST
Page custom Page2Create Page2Leave  PAGE_CUSTOM_SECOND
Page custom pgPageCreate pgPageLeave PAGE_CUSTOM_THIRD

Function Page1Create  
  nsDialogs::Create ${MYPAGE_FIRST}  
  Pop $Dialog1
  ${If} $Dialog1 == error
      Abort
  ${EndIf}  
  ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 12u "${WelcomeTitleText}"

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 13u 100% 42u "${WelcomeText}"

  ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 5% 100u 100% 12u "${InstallSAEText}"
  Pop $InstallSAE
  ; default checked install SAE
  ${NSD_Check} $InstallSAE

  ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 5% 120u 100% 12u "${SkipInstallSAEText}"
  Pop $SkipInstallSAE
  ${NSD_Uncheck} $SkipInstallSAE
  nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd  
  
Function Page1Leave  
  MessageBox MB_OK "Page1 leave"  
  ${NSD_GetState} $InstallSAE $1
  ${NSD_GetState} $SkipInstallSAE $2
  MessageBox MB_OK "$1, $2"  
  ${If} $1 == ${BST_CHECKED}
      Call Page2Create 
  ${ElseIf} $2 == ${BST_CHECKED}
      Call pgPageCreate
  ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd 


Function Page2Create  
  MessageBox MB_OK "Create Page2"  
  nsDialogs::Create ${MYPAGE_SECOND}  
  Pop $Dialog2
  MessageBox MB_OK "$Dialog2"   
  ${If} $Dialog2 == error
      Abort
  ${EndIf}
  ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 12u "This is second page"
  MessageBox MB_OK "Page2 show"  
  nsDialogs::Show  
FunctionEnd  
  
Function Page2Leave  
  MessageBox MB_OK "Page2 leave"  
FunctionEnd 

I hope create mutil dialog for my app install process

What is multi dialog? Format your code properly please...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you need help with creating custom dialogs feel free to use the Install Designer - NSIS tool made for this purpose (also contact me, I am one of its developers).
